How to determine the direct band gap for a semi-metal (bismuth) in Quantum Espresso/BURAI Interface
I have run the Self-Consistent Field calculations and found the highest unoccupied and lowest unoccupied energy level for Bismuth (hR2) crystal structure. Now, bismuth is a semi metal with Fermi level around 0eV. But after taking the mean/average of the highest occupied and unoccupied energy level, my Fermi energy is coming out to be around 9eV. Even in the SCF.out file, the Fermi energy is around 9eV.
I don't understand how to determine the correct Fermi energy, and why is this value coming around 9 when it should be around 0. The aim of my work is to determine the direct band gap at some specific k point (L and T). But without knowing the fermi energy, I can't find the valence and conduction band and hence I can't find the direct band gap at these k points. I have also run the band structure calculation to obtain the band structure for the higher symmetry points. For this, I used seek k-path to find the correct k-path for band structure calculation. But it's useless unless I know how to find the band gap. I don't even have the correct fermi energy I think. Please help me understand where am I going wrong.

Never see a Fermi level of 0eV. In general, when you see Fermi=0eV is because it was shifted. 0eV is not the real value of it.

@Camps Can you please share some resource that explains the calculation of direct band gap at some specific k point from band structure data?

Visually, you can plot the band around the Fermi level and look for the Valence Band Maximum and Conduction Band Minimum, then go to the data for a precise calculation. Or use a script like this (be aware it is a shell script and I didn't test it as I don't play with QuantumEspresso).

The absolute energies that come out from DFT are fictitious Kohn-Sham energies that have no physical meaning. Thus, you can shift the energy spectrum by any arbitrary value without changing any physics.

ohh okay. Thanks
